# (x,y) position of an UI Element in .net maui?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I Have a MAUI project. I want to apply an animation to collectionview items where, when you scroll down each item fades away. I didn't find anything on internet. I had an idea but i don't know how to execute it.
My idea is that when an UI element pass a certain position i apply an animation to that element. Let me know if there is any better solution to my problem.

**How can i know where (x,y) position of an UI element is? and how can i have an event to always check the positions.**

Comment: every `Element` has an `X` and `Y` property that gives its position relative to its parent

Comment: Check the position on a timer.